# How to change the language in Laravel Spark?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

How can I change the language of [Laravel Spark](https://spark.laravel.com/) without editing all the blade-files? I could edit all blade-files and change the labbels/messages with the `lang()` function, but then I don't get the blade updates anymore (or I have to redo this after every update).

Comment: Unfortunately those are your options with the view files having hard-coded English.

Answer (score 1):

I have this very same problem, not only with translations, but also with small changes made to layout and stuff, and, unfortunately, I don't see anything else we, or they, could do now, for translations it could be fairily easy, but for other changes, not really. Changes are verified using MD5, so if you change a single letter in your view you make it unupdatable.

The day after installing it, and changing some views I was already stuck with Spark not being able to upgrade my views because of those changes, and I basically had to go thru the changed files and see if there was something important I would have to copy back to mines.

Thinking that they might at some point add new features to Spark, we would never get them automatically, if we change those views. That's why my decision was to touch only login and register, and let Spark deal with everything else in the Spark panel, while I build a completely separate system around it using my own template. At some point I know I'll have to add settings, so I'll also have to decide about having a second settings page, using my own template, or just edit Spark views and get back to this impossible-to-auto-upgrade state.

Spark is not yet prepared to be multi-language, but now, with Mohamed Said in Laravel Team, we should probably see some changes in this area.

To replace Spark views with yours, you just have to 'override' the `spark::` namespace setting your own directory:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['view']->addNamespace('spark', resource_path('/views/vendor/'.$namespace'));
    }
}
```

This code adds a new folder to the list of ones Laravel Spark already has, in this case it will be the my `resources/view`.

You'll also have to move `AppServiceProvider` to a line above `Laravel\Spark\Providers\SparkServiceProvider::class,` in `config/app.php`.

And you don't have to have all Spark views in this folder, Laravel is kind of eager finding views, so if it doesn't find one, it will try to find it in the original spark folders.

[image]